# how to get better video thumbnail using video url of telegram public channel post

Tags: php, telegram

having link [telegram public channel post: a video](https://t.me/barrtarchannel/557?embed=1) i can find both video URL and it's corresponding thumbnail

[video URL](https://cdn4.telesco.pe/file/qI7fJpHppECb3OApwpZ9D7G1RkCeSowoFBMesubpDvyjOU_Z10VPviijMs2wYllbmUqFN028tdKV3Xzm4143OlmekRS2qr6bqHMRV-U1kfGHlGJVFY23uBreW0y_YM3KOFoW9rHGbXxpbnEqdgucY0w7ssVc5mFUydqWFCvqYRR_0rO3v61gDSVkYRyXsgKINu0Ey_WYpQmCYSAUChj3QVarq4Fsep7tVvBxB4d7N4Bp6rhaAWRLatFjUnUMa9VuZq8yLHsL4AENJpuTdnpgFpkg-kO-bCrZQCJwteTdOYbV-c2s9rC0MeYGW8FUIpk66paRaNBaCTCOUCBAQFa-eQ.mp4)

[thumbnail URL](https://cdn4.telesco.pe/file/MQohaxtOpLMAsmg3qaR2NeWnlksQpnG8kP6B6TP1cJhJkvnqz4cffgPehUQ2OqJ2KMtwLLbuG6-nypaM6NLNTpA1YY5GOaC4U1J_F8R5QLcEZeJ4mDEWvdrk_to2KfzTB2ZnmZSW3ITUWAX06X3Tzz4OHH9GqhOnAb9hh-q7HmJtQpUCsEkMLhqYqWnZdJAGkDrlPatPeDfSgMg0BRBaCWagxcywcgsErcbDpb0QfzmyJeKIZXwINKiyp8mnVFso5roKmBjWa5pRODT3dVyZ9nimfjuJFFGDwFEfTytgpPgY_QIHJ5m1OWKq6PzSbXwlDulXbGZlJnn2pSbjaID8ng)

as you can see the quality of thumb is not good. but i know that telegram provided users different thumb quality options.

[bot API: video section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#video)

[bot API: file section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file)

but to get thumb i need to know the unique_identifier/file_id of the video which i do not know that. please consider that i don't have an admin bot in that channel to receive the unique_id.

is there any way to get the unique_id/file_id from telegram public channel video post? or to get a better quality thumb in other ways?

this is my php code for when i have file_id.

```
    function getfile($file_id) {

    $url = $this->url
        .$this->Token
        .$this->method_getFile
        .$this->parameter_file_id
        .$channelID;
    $result=$this->sendRequest($url);
    return $result;
}
    function sendRequest($url)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;


}
```

please note that going toward FFmpeg is my last choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a better video thumbnail, you should have an admin bot in that channel for reading messages.
In your case when you don't have an admin bot try to look at The [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) (not Bot Api). 
Maybe you will find a solution there.

Comment: do you know what is this file_id used for. this is thumb part of an video i receive by getupdate method. my goal is to get thump picture : ->>>  "thumb":{"file_id":"AAQEABMabp0aAAT1cbidRbh_w68OAAIC","file_size":1199,"width":51,"height":90}

Comment: That file_id is for resending/forwarding files